# How do I fix the "Error in validate_function_class():" within Tidymodels when trying to explore Random Forest Metrics

Tags: random-forest, metrics, training-data, tidymodels

```
`# Create a split object
train_test_split <-
  rsample::initial_split(
    data = nomissingprep,     
    prop = 0.80   
  ) 
# Split the data and build a training and testing data set
train_test_split <- rsample::initial_split(data = nomissingprep,prop = 0.80) 
train.data <- train_test_split %>% training() 
test.data  <- train_test_split %>% testing()

## Recipe Creation
rec <- recipe(preprecentyear ~ ., data = train.data)


## Validation Set

cv_folds <-
  vfold_cv(train.data, 
           v = 5, 
           strata = preprecentyear) 

## Model Fitting -- Random Forest 

library(ranger)
rf_spec <- 
  rand_forest() %>% 
  set_engine("ranger", importance = "impurity") %>% 
  set_mode("classification")

## Workflow --Random Forest 
rf_wflow <-
  workflow() %>%
  add_recipe(rec) %>% 
  add_model(rf_spec) 

##Random Forest Metrics
rf_res <-
  rf_wflow %>% 
  fit_resamples(
    resamples = cv_folds, 
    metrics = metric_set(
      recall, precision, f_meas, 
      accuracy, kap,
      roc_auc, sens, spec),
    control = control_resamples(save_pred = TRUE)
  )

`
```

Error in `validate_function_class()`:
!
The combination of metric functions must be:

- only numeric metrics
- a mix of class metrics and class probability metrics

The following metric function types are being mixed:

- other (recall namespace:caret, precision namespace:caret, spec namespace:readr)
- class (f_meas, accuracy, kap, sens)
- prob (roc_auc)

I am unsure of how to fix this error. All other code prior to the Random Forest Metrics fit well. Any advice is more than welcome. Thanks

Comment: how many classes are in `preprecentyear`? It may be helpful to create a [reprex](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/) with one of the benchmark datasets like `iris` or `mtcars` to help understand your issue better.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: It looks like some of the metric functions are not being identified because of confusing with other package namespaces. What happens if you run this without loading caret? And/or using `tidymodels::tidymodels_prefer()`?

Answer (score 0):

```
log_res <- 
  tidymodels::tidymodels_prefer( log_wflow %>% 
  fit_resamples(
    resamples = cross_validation, 
    metrics = metric_set(
    kap, sensitivity, specificity, precision_vec,  recall_vec),
    control = control_resamples(
      save_pred = TRUE)
  ) 
  )  
log_res
```

Try it this way.